# jQuery if else or switch statement for two menus

Tags: jquery, if-statement, switch-statement

I have a menu button on my website, it opens a menu bar with options.  When you click on one of the options it opens a new div below with a PDF containing information.  Everything works, but I have one main problem.  When I click on a new link, the old link doesn't go away.  My links keep stacking on top of each other and I have to click on all of them again in order to make the new divs go away.

I was looking into a switch statement to maybe solve this.  Like if a user clicks on a menu option, the menu option opens and then if they click on another menu options the old menu options closes and the new ones opens.

here is my code so far,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$( "#mainMenu" ).click(function() {
$( "#flexMenu" ).toggle("slow");
});

/*If mainMenu closes, close all over menus*/

/*if dinnerButton is pressed, close any other menus open besides mainMenu 
  than open dinner menu*/

$( "#dinnerButton" ).click(function() {
$( "#menuDropDinner" ).toggle("slow");
});

$( "#lunchButton" ).click(function() {
$( "#menuDropLunch" ).toggle("slow");
});

$( "#wineButton" ).click(function() {
$( "#menuDropWine" ).toggle("slow");
});

$( "#dolciButton" ).click(function() {
$( "#menuDropDolci" ).toggle("slow");
});

});
```

Would a series of if else statement be easier then a possible switch statement?

example of what I have so far is here.  You can see what I'm talking about by pressing the Menu link and the options that come from it.

www.littleroomproductions.com/roma/

Comment: can you give us a working example? (using jsfiddle or some similar service)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Always explicitly slideDown/slideUp (or show()/hide(), or whatever). The toggle idea is great when only one element is being manipulated, but when several can be open/closed, it is always best to be explicit.
2. Give all a class (e.g. `divBtn`) and use that to determine that a button was clicked (any button).
3. Give all drop menu DIVs a class and, every time a button is clicked, close all drop menu divs (even the ones already closed).
4. Put a hyphen or _underscore between "name" and "Button" (e.g. `dinner_Button`), and extract that name to use in opening the correct drop menu.

Code example:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/1w0jrLkx/)</kbd>

jQuery/javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.divBtn').click(function(){
        $('.dropDIV').slideUp(); //close all drop menu divs

        var mnu = this.id.split('_')[0];
        mnu = toTitleCase(mnu);
        $('#menuDrop'+mnu).slideDown('slow'); //open the correct drop menu
    });
});

function toTitleCase(str){
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
}
```

---

To make the button `slideUp()` an opened DIV if the same button is clicked again, just add a test: only open the div if the div is not visible:

<kbd>[**Revised jQuery Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/1w0jrLkx/2/)</kbd>

```
var mnu = this.id.split('_')[0];
mnu = toTitleCase(mnu);
if ( !$('#menuDrop'+mnu).is(':visible') ){
    $('#menuDrop'+mnu).slideDown('slow');
}
```

Note: Caught an error -- was still using `.toggle()` instead of explicit `slideDown`. Fixed.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I'll start trying to add some of this.  I added a link above to the website I'm working on if you wanted to see how the menu thing was working

Comment: also, does slideDown toggle a div that is currently hidden?

Comment: tested slideDown and it does hide the div.  However, now its stuck open and I can't get it to close by clicking back on it

Comment: See new section at bottom of answer.  Clicking any button will close all open divs. Div associated with button will only `slideDown` IF the div is not already open.